# For any open set $U$ in $M$ and a point $p∈U$, there is a coordinate open set $U_α$ such that $p∈U_α⊂U.$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading the following lemma in L. Tu book on manifolds. There is a statement in this proof that I didn't see that in this book before. That is, for any open set $U$ in $M$ and a point $p∈U$, there is a coordinate open set $U_α$ such that

$$p∈U_α⊂U.$$

I don't know how the author has concluded this statement. Could anyone explain this for me, please? Here is the lemma and it's proof in book.

**Lemma.** A manifold $M$ has a countable basis consisting of coordinate open sets.

**Proof.** Let ${(U_α,φ_α)}$ be the maximal atlas on $M$ and $\mathcal B=\{B_i\}$ a countable basis for $M$. For each coordinate open set $U_α$ and point $p∈U_α$, choose a basic open set $B_{p,α}∈\mathcal B$ such that

$$p∈B_{p,α}⊂U_α.$$

The collection $\{B_{p,α}\}$, without duplicate elements, is a subcollection of $B$ and is therefore countable.

For any open set $U$ in $M$ and a point $p∈U$, there is a coordinate open set $U_α$ such that

$$p∈U_α⊂U.$$

Hence,

$$p∈B_{p,α}⊂U,$$

which shows that $\{B_{p,α}\}$ is a basis for $M$.

Comment: I think I have to prove that a countable subcollection of $\{U_\alpha\}$ forms a basis. But instead it shows that $\{B_{p,\alpha}\}$ forms a basis. Why so? Is it straightforward?

Comment: @TamasKantiGarai I think $(B_{p,\alpha}, \varphi_{\alpha} \mid _{B_{p,\alpha}})$ also gives a chart, so $\{B_{p,\alpha} \} \subset \{U_{\alpha} \}$, and $\{B_{p,\alpha}\}$ forms a basis suggests that a countable subcollection of $\{U_\alpha\}$ forms a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a chart $(U_\beta, \varphi_\beta)$ around $p$. Then $(U_\alpha,
 \varphi_\alpha) \doteq (U_\beta \cap U, \varphi_\beta\big|_{U_\alpha \cap U})$ is again a chart around $p$, whose domain satisfies $U_\alpha\subseteq U$.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask another question? In line 4 of proof, the collection $\{B_{p,\alpha}\}$ is just over $\alpha$ or both $p$ and $\alpha$? That is, $\{B_{p,\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I}$ or $\{B_{p,\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in I, p\in U_\alpha}$?

Comment: Both $p$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: Apologies for digging up an old post, but how do we know that these charts are compatible with the rest of the atlas? Is this necessary to show (and if it is, how would we do that?) or is the atlas being maximal automatically imply that it contains this chart as well?

Comment: Technically it is necessary to show that $(U_\beta\cap U, \varphi_\beta\big|_{U_\beta\cap U})$ is compatible with the rest of the atlas, but this is trivial: the transition maps are restrictions of "larger" transition maps which are already know to be smooth (since $(U_\beta,\varphi_\beta)$ is in the atlas by assumption). Then (and only then) we conclude that $(U_\beta\cap U, \varphi_\beta\big|_{U_\beta\cap U})$ is also in the atlas, by maximality.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!